# Enable browser notification on localhost

Tags: javascript, browser, localhost

How I can enable browser notification when I'm using localhost, when writing in console `Notification.requestPermission();` nothing appear but on any regular site write in console `Notification.requestPermission();` the permission is requested.

How I can enable it to test my code ?
Thank you very much in advance ...

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Perhaps you have already blocked permission for notifications on that origin.

Comment: I'm not blocked I'm sure about this

Comment: You need to have a SSL on your domain, thus you cannot do this on Localhost without one.
You can add this to your safe url's list on chrome to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should be working.. may be you missed something else..
Please try this code..

### Usage

```
sendNotification({
  title: 'New Notification',
  message: 'Your message goes here',
  icon:'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mixed-rounded-flat-icon/512/megaphone-64.png',
  clickCallback: function () {
    alert('do something when clicked on notification');
  }
});
```

### Function

```
function sendNotification (data) {
    if (data == undefined || !data) { return false }
    var title = (data.title === undefined) ? 'Notification' : data.title
    var clickCallback = data.clickCallback
    var message = (data.message === undefined) ? 'null' : data.message
    var icon = (data.icon === undefined) ? 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/mixed-rounded-flat-icon/512/megaphone-64.png' : data.icon
    var sendNotification = function (){
        var notification = new Notification(title, {
            icon: icon,
            body: message
        })
        if (clickCallback !== undefined) {
            notification.onclick = function () {
                clickCallback()
                notification.close()
            }
        }
    }

    if (!window.Notification) {
        return false
    } else {
        if (Notification.permission === 'default') {
            Notification.requestPermission(function (p) {
                if (p !== 'denied') {
                    sendNotification()
                }
            })
        } else {
            sendNotification()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check browser version whether it has support for notification and try by using http://{localhost ip} instead of localhost/xyz.

Comment: it's work but I face another problem, BTW why it work with localhost IP instead of domain name ? Thank you

Comment: the problem was in setting, it was allow always, it changed to ask first
But really thank you
and I appreciate if answe me about my question above

Comment: I don`t know why this answer got downgraded as this is the correct answer - you need to use IP e.g. 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. It frustrated me too until I thought about it and checked.

Comment: see my suggestion below how to edit the `UserNotificationPermissions.plist`

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu, you should run the chrome instance this way

`whereis google-chrome` to find your executable

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://your-domain.dev:80
```

Remember to close all other instances of chrome before doing that (pkill -9 chrome)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that this flag has been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS you may edit the `UserNotificationPermissions.plist` in the  `~/Library/Safari`. You may use Xcode in sudo

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Open the file (use `CMD+SHIFT+.` to display hidden folders/files)
Duplicate or create a new item here by using `localhost` or anything else

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A good implementation for TypeScript could be

```js
  export const browserNotification = (title: string, body: string = "", options = {}) => {
    try {
      if (typeof window === "undefined" || !Notification) {
        return;
      }

      Notification.requestPermission().then(permission => {
        if (permission === "granted") {
          new Notification(title, { ...options, body });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      // Safari doesn't return a promise for requestPermissions and it
      // throws a TypeError. It takes a callback as the first argument
      // instead.
      if (error instanceof TypeError) {
        Notification.requestPermission(() => {
          new Notification(title, { ...options, body });
        });
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up the console then enable notifications on localhost with

```js
window.Notification.requestPermission();
```

Click on "Allow" in the top left.

Then you can send notifications like this

```js
new window.Notification(
    'Notification title text',
    {
        body: 'notification body text',
        badge: '/img/some-image.png',
        icon: '/img/some-image.png',
    },
);
```